# Identifying centre of rarefaction and compression of a graph in a st graph

Tags: waves, acoustics

[image]

We know that for a sound wave traveling to the right, the centre of compression occurs at $s = 0$ and $\frac{ds}{dt} > 0$ (take right direction as positve i.e. traveling to the right too!). And centre of rarefaction occurs in $s = 0$ and $\frac{ds}{dt} < 0$. I have seen some explanation of this using simulation, I wonder what is the theoretical/mathematical proof for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

s=0 and ds/dt > 0 means that the displacement has been increasing, implying compression since it would normally require a force.

s=0 and ds/dt < 0 means that the displacement has been decreasing, implying decompression since it would normally require reducing the force.

The center of compression/decompression s = 0 is the displacement that would occur with no applied force.

Comment: Why displacement is increasing implies force is given to the particle? for me it simply means that the particle is traveling to the right.

Comment: When the particle moves away from s=0, it does so against some tension so it requires a force. Also the particle has mass so it requires a force to impart a movement.

Comment: When $\frac{ds}{dt} < 0$, it can also be moving away from $s = 0$ but why in that case it means reducing the force?

Comment: If at the same time s=0, ie. crossing the s=0 axis, a reduction in force would be required to get there.  After that an increase in force would be required.  Modified my answer.

Comment: I think I get it now, is it right to say that for a longitudinal wave travelling to the right, the tension is always towards the left?

Comment: The tension on a given particle would vary--first to the right then to the left as a half cycle of a wave passes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound#Longitudinal_and_transverse_waves

Comment: I still don't quite understand what do you mean by reducing/increasing the force. Since as you have mentioned, in both the center of compression and decompression the applied force at that instant is 0. The only thing that differs between center of compression and decompression is that in one of them, the force changes from towards positive to towards negative; and in another the force changes from towards negative to positive. So in both cases, the force reduces to 0 and reverses the direction shortly after that. What do you mean by a decrease/increase in force then? Did I get something wrong