# Why is the centre of compression different for two different graphs of a longitudinal wave?

Tags: waves

According to the first picture, the centre of compression corresponds with the peak of the wave.

However, in the second picture, the centre of compression lies on the x-axis. This is because to the left side of the compression point on the x-axis, the particles move to the right. On the right side, the particles move to the left. This causes compression at the red points.

What causes this difference and which one is correct?
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: Check this old post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/578752/identifying-centre-of-rarefaction-and-compression-of-a-graph-in-a-st-graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text under the second picture is right. The slope of the displacement graph determines the amount of compression/rarefaction. The waveform in the first picture shows something else than displacement. For sound it could be pressure but I have no clue what the author is displaying.

Answer (score 0):

A wave like this consists of to components: displacement and compression/refraction (or pressure). These are 90 degrees out of, i.e. there is maximum pressure where displacement is zero and there is maximum displacement where the pressure is zero.

How the graph looks like depends on what quantities you draw: displacement or pressure. The first seem show pressure, the second one displacement. It's hard to tell for the first one, because it's not properly labeled.

You will have a pressure maxima or minima where the displacement is 0, although you can't easily tell whether it's a minimum or maximum from the displacement alone.